# how to combine column to create primary key to add 2 Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am beginner in SQL i have to add 2 tables by aggregating column(date,month year).
I have to find festival wise total sale.
Any effort will be appreciated

```
Table1      
date month  year sales
1   1     1995  $12 
2   10    1997  $36 
3   2     1995  $29 
4   4     1998  $26 

    Table2      
date month  year    Festival
5   1     1995  Chrismus
6   12    1998  Chrismus
7   4     1994  New_year
3   6     2000  New_year
```

Comment: Please share the expected output

Comment: I have to find festival wise sale.

Comment: On what terms you mean `wise` ? Do you mean the `SUM` of each festival day?

Comment: @Peter Darmis  yes

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you have a Sales table (total sales, by day) and a Calendar table (holiday names, by day). You'd like to see the total sales by holiday.

This is a VERY common SQL task, so it's worth getting used to this pattern:

1. Join the two tables on day, month, and year. This will give you a single combined table with the holiday names for each relevant day.
2. Take the sum of sales, grouped by holiday name and year. This will give you the total amount sold per holiday each year.

If you want to see the total sales per holiday period, then the steps are a bit similar, but join on month instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.date t1.month  t1.year sum(t1.sales) as sales,
t2.Festival
FROM Table1 t1,Table2 t1
WHERE t1.date=t2.date
and t1.month=t2.month
and t1.year=t2.year
GROUP BY t1.date ,t1.month,  t1.year,t2.Festival;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided a description on the desired output i am guessing that this is an expenses `SUM` per `date`, `month`, `year`. So in that case you might be looking something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(t1.sales) AS daily_sum, t2.Festival, t1.date, t1.month, t1.year FROM Table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.date = t2.date AND t1.month = t2.month AND t1.year = t2.year GROUP BY t1.date,t1.month,t1.year;
```

There is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0aef6/7) available to check out with different occasions of `GROUP BY` and the number of fields the tables are joined.

PS: You should use `DATE` fields for your expense or income entries so your `Table1` could have only two fields a date and a sales, and `Table2` could be a table with 3 fields called date_start, date_end, festival. That would determine the duration of the festival for you each year.